# How to use String.prototype as a function in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to use Kolner phonetic for my app but I dont know how to use that like a function. Here are two files and for that reason I need to use that like hooks or like function.
The first block of code is the algorithm for phonetic and the second is the implementation.

```js
String.prototype.colophonetics = (function(){

    var substitution = {'ä': 'a', 'ö': 'o', 'ü': 'u', 'ß': 'ss', 'ph': 'f'}
    var exceptions_leading = {
        4: ["ca","ch","ck","cl","co","cq","cu","cx"],
        8: ["dc","ds","dz","tc","ts","tz"]
    };
    var exceptions_following = ["sc","zc","cx","kx","qx"];
    var coding_table = {
        0:  "aeijouy",
        1:  "bp",
        2:  "dt",
        3:  "fvw",
        4:  "cgkq",
        48: "x",
        5:  "l",
        6:  "mn",
        7:  "r",
        8:  "csz"
    };

    if(Array.prototype.contains === undefined){
        Array.prototype.contains = function(element){
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
                if (this[i] == element) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    return function(word){

        var word = word || this + "";

        if(typeof word === 'string' && word.indexOf(' ') !== -1){
            word = word.split(' ');
        }

        if(typeof word === 'object'){
            var phons = [];
            for(i in word){
                phons.push(arguments.callee(word[i]));
            }
            return phons.join(' ');
        }

        if(typeof word !== 'string'){
            return '';
        }

        word = word.toLowerCase();
        for(s in substitution){
            word = word.replace(new RegExp(s, "g"), substitution[s]);
        }

        var value = [];
        var length = word.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){

            var l       = word.substr(i, 1);
            value[i]    = '';

            if(i === 0 && length > 1 && word[i] + word[i+1] === 'cr'){
                value[i] = 4;
            }

            for(code in exceptions_leading){
                if(exceptions_leading[code].contains(word[i] + word[i+1])){
                    value[i] = parseInt(code);
                }
            }

            if(i !== 0 && exceptions_following.contains(word[i-1] + word[i])){
                value[i] = 8;
            }

            if(value[i] == ''){
                for(code in coding_table){
                    if(coding_table[code].indexOf(l) !== -1){
                        value[i] = parseInt(code);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(var i = 1; i < length; i++){
            if(value[i] == value[i-1]){
                value[i] = "";
            }
            if(value[i] == 0){
                value[i] = "";
            }
        }

        return value.join('') + "";
    }

})();
```

I need like this to use in React JS because the main problem is I am new with React.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../colophonetics.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var string = "Rønne Ronne Ranne Runne Ramme";
        document.write(string + ": " + string.colophonetics() + "<br/>");
        
    </script>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @valton, welcome to SO. Most react projects use a module bundler like webpack which allows us to write [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). Are you using webpack or something similar? If so I would move these functions into their own file and import them when they are needed. It doesn't need to be a `hook`. Those are for extending state / effects. This is purely computation.

Comment: Hi @mattdevio, thanks for the quick reply. I'm not using webpack, I just wanted to implement this phonetic function for an input element in the search value for my react-js app.